# Load images on background thread in Spritekit

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, ios7, sprite-kit

Right guys, I have scroll view in my SKScene running from a SKAction with the following code -

```
    for (int i=0; i<[listOfImages count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *myDic = [listOfImages objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *urlImage = [myDic objectForKey:@"product_image"];


        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlImage];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *cacheImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/4+leftMargin, 0, cacheImage.size.width/2, cacheImage.size.height/2)];
                [image setImage:cacheImage];

                image.tag = tag;
                image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [scrollView addSubview:image];
                UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
                recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
                recognizer.delegate = self;
                [image addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
                [image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

                leftMargin += SCREEN_WIDTH;
                tagValue += 1;
                tag += 1;


    }
```

I need to understand how to load the images in the background as there are almost 140 images to load and its taking 5 minutes to load everything and show. Please help me out !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a queue where one load ending triggers another, as opposed to triggering all the loads at once.

I did a google search and got this if you need help with applying the concept :

http://khanlou.com/2012/08/asynchronous-downloaded-images-with-caching/

Comment: even i want to do that!..but could you guide me to a tutorial please!! this is my first app!

Comment: I added a link. But you should probably first do a search on here for "ios Asynchronous image loading" and add any other keywords that match your situation.

Comment: It's likely that you need to take a step back and learn some foundational concepts that you can apply to what you are trying to do. Ask yourself why they are laid out like that, and how you can change that to suit your requirements.

Comment: even i feel the same thing..its been more than 24 hrs and i am stuck with this!.. i wish someone had done uiscrollview in spritekit!